# Oracle ORA-00937: not a single-group group function in Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am working on Hibernate query. This query works fine with MySQL but fails in Oracle and postgreSQL.

```
SELECT MIN(t.startTime) AS StartTime,
MAX(t.endTime) AS EndTime,
(SELECT SUM(t2.occurances) from table2 as t2)
from table1 as t1
```

And I am getting error-

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

How do I fix this problem? This table returns only one row. If I add group by by adding an extra column in SELECT it returns more than one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `GROUP BY` for third column:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.startTime) AS StartTime,
  MAX(t1.endTime) AS EndTime,
  (SELECT SUM(t2.occurances) FROM table2 t2) as occurances
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY 3
```

This query returns one row.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively you can use additional aggregate function (for example `MAX`), then `GROUP BY` is not required:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.startTime) AS StartTime,
  MAX(t1.endTime) AS EndTime,
  MAX( (SELECT SUM(t2.occurances) FROM table2 t2) ) as occurances
FROM table1 t1
```

Comment: Now I get this - ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway I can do it without GROUP BY?

Comment: @Sayan added query without `GROUP BY`; tested on MySQL, Oracle.

Comment: Thank you! But I have hit this Hibernate error here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9331

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for MySQL because of MySQL extensions to the `group by`.  Unfortunately, subqueries are not treated as "constant"s by the compiler when it looks at aggregation queries.  So, this is just another expression not in the `group by` clause.

Here is a way to write the query that is compatible for all three databases (but not for Hibernate):

```
SELECT MIN(t.startTime) AS StartTime, MAX(t.endTime) AS EndTime, MAX(occurrences)
from table1 t1 cross join
     (SELECT SUM(t2.occurrences) as occurrences from table2 t2) t2;
```

I should add, you also cannot add the subquery to the `group by` clause, although the following will work in Oracle and Postgres:

```
SELECT MIN(t.startTime) AS StartTime, MAX(t.endTime) AS EndTime,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.occurances) from table2 t2)
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY 3;
```

EDIT:

HQL is quite restrictive compared to standard SQL.  The following comes *close* two what you want, but it returns at least two rows instead of 1:

```
select t.starttime, t.endtime, (SELECT SUM(t2.occurances) from table2 t2)
from table1 t
where t.starttime = (select min(starttime) from table1) or
      t.endtime = (select max(endtime) from table1);
```

Comment: But it fails in MySQL!

Comment: @Sayan . . . The first version should work in all three databases (now that I've removed the `as` from the table aliases).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with t1 as (
    SELECT MIN(t.startTime) AS StartTime,
    MAX(t.endTime) AS EndTime
    from table1 as t1
), t2 as (
    SELECT SUM(t2.occurances) occurances from table2 as t2
)
select t1.starttime, t1.endtime, t2.occurances
  from t1, t2
```